# Query Failed Error: Views cannot be queried through prefix. Partial list of the matched views are

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am trying to query a dataset with multiple tables and equivalent views. I am trying to query just the tables using _table_suffix, but it returns an error "Query Failed Error: Views cannot be queried through prefix. Partial list of the matched views-......" 
I cannot remove the views from the dataset. Is there a way to query the tables only and ignore the views?

```
SELECT COUNT(*), _table_suffix, DATE(created)
FROM `dataset.viewed_*`
WHERE _table_suffix like '%_page'
```

Comment: Not sure why you have tagged this with [google-analytics]?

Answer (score 3):

Your options are:

- Recreate the views under different names, so that the `viewed_` prefix doesn't match them.
- Use a longer prefix than `viewed_` (if possible) when matching the table names, so that the view names aren't included.
- Migrate your tables to a single [partitioned table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables) so that you don't need to use a wildcard.

I would suggest the third option if at all possible; using a partitioned table is much better than trying to maintain multiple tables with a common schema.