# BigQuery: dynamically select table by the current date in Standard SQL?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to find the table of the current date of

```
SELECT * 
FROM `da`.`m`.`ga_realtime_20190306`
```

but not working

```
SELECT * 
FROM `da`.`m`.`CONCAT('ga_realtime_', FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', CURRENT_DATE())`
```

How can I dynamically select a table with `CURRENT_DATE` and the BigQuery Standard query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use wildcard and `_TABLE_SUFFIX`

```
SELECT
  field1,
  field2,
  field3
FROM
  `my_dataset.ga_realtime_*`
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX = FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', CURRENT_DATE())
```

Comment: Great idea +1 but what about with view? This works with tables but views firing `"Error: Views cannot be queried through prefix. Partial list of the matched views are:"`. I found this below

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52521822/query-failed-error-views-cannot-be-queried-through-prefix-partial-list-of-the

and it suggest to avoid wildcards and views, not sure whether any dynamic selecting way for views?

Comment: So apparently your wildcard matches some views as well. Please resolve this by renaming - moving. The third recommendation is good as well from Elliott, you could move the day tables into a partitioned table each day.