# Tables with unapplied upsert data cannot be queried through prefix (query to INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-datastream

In BigQuery I have a dataset `my_project_id.my_dataset` with tables created by Google Datastream, copied over from PostgreSQL partitioned table.

I want to query the [PARTITIONS view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-partitions) in this dataset.

```sql
SELECT * FROM `my_project_id.my_dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS`
```

But I am getting this error

> Tables with unapplied upsert data cannot be queried through prefix.
> First table with upsert data is
> my_project_id:my_dataset.some_table.

*This is my second question about the same error in different, but seemed to be more affecting scenario. First question:
[Tables with unapplied upsert data cannot be queried through prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77214046/tables-with-unapplied-upsert-data-cannot-be-queried-through-prefix)*.